# Input of an LSTM layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

How to feed output of a "fully_connected" layer to an LSTM layer in Tensorflow. I am trying the following code:

```
hidden1 = fully_connected(X, n_hidden1, scope="hidden1")
hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1, n_hidden2, scope="hidden2")
hidden3 = fully_connected(hidden2, n_hidden3, scope="hidden3")
lstm=tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnCompatibleLSTMCell(n_lstm)
initial_state = lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
lstm_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, hidden3, 
initial_state=initial_state)
output = fully_connected(lstm, n_outputs,scope="outputs",activation_fn=None)
```

An LSTM layer requires a 3D tensor as input e.g. (batch_size,max_time, num_features) but output of a "fully_connected" layer is a 1D tensor.

How to implement neural network where input of LSTM layer is output of a "fully_connected" layer in Tensorflow?

Thanks for Helping!!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If the output is naturally *not* a sequence, why pass it into LSTM?

Comment: I am trying to predict time series data. Input to hidden1 layer is last 15 values of time series and output of the network is the predicted value at next time step. I am trying to capture long range dependence through LSTM.

Comment: I have found [this](https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/Understanding-LSTM-in-Tensorflow-MNIST/) very good blog about Tensorflow LSTM.